# node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-ec2, npm, npm-install

```
uws@9.14.0 install /var/www/html/my-app/node_modules/uws
node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0
```

> Error: Package install failed, see above.

I got this error while hit the `ng new my-app`

Using;

- Angular CLI: 1.7.3
- Node: 9.9.0
- OS: linux x64 AWS EC2
- npm: 5.6.0

Answer (score 1):

you need to globally install node-gyp and socket.io

```
# cd ~
# npm install -g node-gyp
# npm install socket.io
```

Comment: you should try deleting your node-gyp folder and try again from i.e., /home/username/.node-gyp or /Users/username/.node-gyp